# Poker Academy Pro or an alternative

Tags: software

Several years back I trained with a copy of Poker Academy Pro.

[image: Poker Academy PRO]

I played tens of thousands of hands and did a lot to improve my game.  I changed computers to an iMac some time ago and never reinstalled it, so its now long lost and gone.

I've searched with Google to find the company and the newest version, but while one can download it from [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Poker-Academy-Pro/3000-2095_4-11629989.html) I can't find a link to get or pay for an activation code.

Questions:

- Does the company still exist?
- How can one get an activation code?
- Can anyone suggest a comparable alternative?
- What is the best poker training software?

Thanks.

Comment: The company does not exist, therefore there is no way to gain an activation code. I am currently compiling a list for a relevant software. Are you looking for native software or will training sites do as well?

Comment: @Chris -- Thanks for the reply.  Happy to use a training site, although having something running on a local machine would likely speed up response time for the bots.  If you do come across anything useful, please advise.

Comment: @Chris did you ever complete your list?

Comment: Aww man, that was like 5 years ago! I will say, try DD Poker if you're looking to play fast local games against an OK AI.

Answer (score 7):

The only way you can get this program is to download it through torrent, although that it illegal so I am not suggesting it, although I am telling you that I might have done it and it is probably possible if you google search "Poker academy pro torrent". If you try to find a good torrent, use a torrent downloading program and go from there you will have it, I might have it now and it might be pretty dam good.